# What is the best way to store css data inside database and call it similar to how a css file would be

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am attempting to store css files inside database and call them in the most effective wa using PHP.  I know I can include a style.php file and just do a query to get the data; however, not sure if that is the best way or not.  I'd prefer to not have

```
<style>
#blah { }
#blah 2 { }
etc.
</style>
```

show up on every page.  I am attempting to make this work similar to how a typical css file would work where it is just a link similar to the way it is below. I have read about people using 
html page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php" />
```

style.php page:

```
header("Content-Type: text/css");
```

however, have also seen that that doesn't work well with IE.

So does anyone have any recommendations on how I can do this in the best way for all browsers?

Comment: I'm posting this not as a duplicate.  I'm posting this as to find a solution that will work the best.  He is asking why it isnt working.  I'm not asking that.  I've seen that article before.  I'm asking for the solution that will work in all browsers because that method isn't working at ALL for me in ANY browser.  I just posted that to show that I've attempted and researched that.  Just because I put the code in there doesn't mean I'm asking the same queston

Comment: Doing that or linking css file or whatever method you will use is the same security level and as i think have the same performance so why you need to do that if all methods are the same ?try to not reinvent tier :) @KDJ127

Comment: I just need the css inside database.  I'm not trying to increase security.

Comment: One approach would be to rewrite the filename with htaccess from .php to .css, then it would act as any css file...

Comment: @jtheman that seems like a decent idea.  How would I do this?  I know how to do a basic rewrite; however, not sure how to rewrite an extension after the page loads the php.  Not sure if this makes sense or not.

Comment: why you don't try to store what are you trying to store from css code inside file not inside a database then store the name of your generated file inside the database i think that you are searching a way for a dynamic css and by this way i think you will have the same approach :) @KDJ127

Comment: @last breath, my approach to this was more or less because I want the users of the css to be able to modify the css and I'm not sure how to load code from a file into a textbox and allow modifications if it is stored in a file and not in the database.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @KDJ127 loading text from a flat file:  `$contents = file_get_contents(path/to/file)`, print where appropriate.  When its time to save:  `file_put_contents(path/to/file, $contents)`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php,  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: @KDJ127 - I think that your logic went out of the window a long time ago. Who is he?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my suggestion here as an answer.

Try adding an .htaccess file if you don't have one. Include the lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^style\.css$ style.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```

This would rewrite `style.css` to the server as `style.php` and treat it correctly as an executable script. Remember to keep the header so that the file returned is identical to a static css file. Also note that css'es stay in the browser cache so to actually reload the css you would either need to change cache settings in htaccess, change the filename or tell your visitors to manually reload the page.

Comment: Your visitors browsers will query your server for the file style.css, and the server returns the file generated from php disguised as css.

Comment: Inside my style.php page, I have the php code loading the css from database.  Then on the index page, I have: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  -> is that right?  Becuase I have this and tested it but it isn't styling the page.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but you will need to have the rewrite working. Be sure to check with your preferred debug tool that the file is actually loaded. You could also try just loading the style.css directly and see if you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a javascript-class and use JQuery. The each of queries would et the correct class using addClass. The class you are adding would be created dynamicly in the javascript-class.